# javascript any type of Redirection not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple javascript that checks if the user puts the correct username and password and be redirected to the admin page but it does not work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login').click(function(){
var username = $('#user').val();
var password = $('#pass').val();

if(username == "")
{
  $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please type username</span>");
  return false;
}

if(password == "")
{
  $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span id='error'>Please type password</span>");
  return false;
}

if(username == "admin" && password == "admin")
{
  window.location("registrar.html");
}
else
{
  alert("Incorrect Username or Password");
}
});
});
```

I already tried different ways but it still not work..
I tried also to put the full address of the page http://localhost/folder/registrar.html but not working also...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
window.location("registrar.html");
```

With:

```
window.location.href = "registrar.html";
```

Comment: there's not even errors that's why I can't check if what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @SilverRay : hmmm, that is frustrating have you tried `window.location.replace("registrar.html");` and `window.location = "registrar.html";`?

Comment: Yes, that's the first code that I used before I replace it with the window.location...

Comment: I am using this two ajax libraries http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js and http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js. Is the libraries may cause this problem?

Comment: Ok I solve my problem by adding php and there the redirection happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still want to know why the simpliest code does not work even though I followed the syntax correctly that was posted by others....

Answer (score 0):

This the solution that I come out. I add this php

```
session_start();

$error = $user = $pass = "";
$check = "";

if(!empty($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['pass']))
{
$user = htmlentities($_GET['user']);
$pass = htmlentities($_GET['pass']);

if($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin")
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;

    header("Location: registrar.html");
   }
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Username or Password');
    window.location.href = 'login.html';</script>";
}
}
```

and removing this code to the javascript:

```
if(username == "admin" && password == "admin")
{
  window.location = "registrar.html";
}
else
{
  alert("Incorrect Username or Password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// same as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("registrar.html");

// same as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "registrar.html";
```